# Azure Appinsights vs Log Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

Currently I am logging my custom log messages to an Azure Table.

Now I need to automatically trigger the sending of emails based on log types and also need to generate an analysis report from the log messages.

Which service is more suitable to get this done? Azure Application Insights or Azure Log Analytics?

Comment: Can you explain your scenario a bit better? Specifically: in which cases would you need to send an email? How often? What do you mean by "analysed report"? What type of analysis?

Comment: in which cases would you need to send an email? 
   Whenever a custom error message is logged i need to trigger an email What do you mean by "analysed report"? What type of analysis?                         I need to create a report based on different log types and how frequently the error messages are getting logged

Comment: Downvoting for unresponsiveness to questions

Answer (score 3):

I think **Application Insights** will fit both - creating reports as well as sending out emails. You can do the same with Log Analytics but the difference is that Log Analytics is basically a logical storage of all your log data and you can create custom reports, alerts etc. across many different services. In addition, everything can be nicely visualized in OMS.

As being said in the comments, you need to describe a bit more about the scenario.